# Edit custom field options using API

Tags: rally

We are trying to implement a new custom field (drop down list) which would need to be updated regularly with new options. Rather than editing the available options by hand, we were hoping to write a script which would update the custom field's options automatically by using the Rally API. Is this possible, or is it only possible to use the API to edit the records themselves?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is currently not possible to manipulate custom fields through the API due to the fact that all the fields on AttributeDefinition are read-only.

I would encourage you to submit an idea for this at https://ideas.rallydev.com.